# Rails 4 mensagens de erro traduzidas, trocar nome do model e atributos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, i18n

Olá, estou iniciando em rails e estou apanhando para tratar as mensagens de erros em pt-BR. Estou usando MongoDB/Mongoid para a camada de banco de dados.

Possuo um model **user**, com atributos **name**, **email** e **password**.

Baixei a gem 'rails-i18n', e o arquivo **pt-BR.yml** do diretório oficial do github.

As mensagens estão OK, porém, no botão cadastrar está escrito "Criar **User**", as mensagens de erro ficam como "**Name** não pode ficar em branco".

Gostaria de traduzir o nome do model e os seus atributos. Pelo que vi é feito diretamente no arquivo **pt-BR.yml**. O meu esta na estrutura abaixo, porém ainda não funciona.

```
    pt-BR:
      activerecord:
        models:
          user: 
            one: "Usuário"
            other: "Usuários"
        attributes:
          user/name: "Nome"
          user/email: "E-mail"
          user/password: "Senha"
          user/password_confirmation: "Senha Confirmação"
      date:
        abbr_day_names:
        - Dom
        - Seg
        - Ter
        - Qua
        - Qui
        - Sex
        - Sáb
        abbr_month_names:
        -
        - Jan
        - Fev
        - Mar
        - Abr
        - Mai
        - Jun
        - Jul
        - Ago
        - Set
        - Out
        - Nov
        - Dez
        day_names:
        - Domingo
        - Segunda
        - Terça
        - Quarta
        - Quinta
        - Sexta
        - Sábado
        formats:
          default: ! '%d/%m/%Y'
          long: ! '%d de %B de %Y'
          short: ! '%d de %B'
        month_names:
        -
        - Janeiro
        - Fevereiro
        - Março
        - Abril
        - Maio
        - Junho
        - Julho
        - Agosto
        - Setembro
        - Outubro
        - Novembro
        - Dezembro
        order:
        - :day
        - :month
        - :year
      datetime:
        distance_in_words:
          about_x_hours:
            one: aproximadamente 1 hora
            other: aproximadamente %{count} horas
          about_x_months:
            one: aproximadamente 1 mês
            other: aproximadamente %{count} meses
          about_x_years:
            one: aproximadamente 1 ano
            other: aproximadamente %{count} anos
          almost_x_years:
            one: quase 1 ano
            other: quase %{count} anos
          half_a_minute: meio minuto
          less_than_x_minutes:
            one: menos de um minuto
            other: menos de %{count} minutos
          less_than_x_seconds:
            one: menos de 1 segundo
            other: menos de %{count} segundos
          over_x_years:
            one: mais de 1 ano
            other: mais de %{count} anos
          x_days:
            one: 1 dia
            other: ! '%{count} dias'
          x_minutes:
            one: 1 minuto
            other: ! '%{count} minutos'
          x_months:
            one: 1 mês
            other: ! '%{count} meses'
          x_seconds:
            one: 1 segundo
            other: ! '%{count} segundos'
        prompts:
          day: Dia
          hour: Hora
          minute: Minuto
          month: Mês
          second: Segundo
          year: Ano 
      errors:        
        format: ! '%{attribute} %{message}'
        messages:      
          accepted: deve ser aceito
          blank: não pode ficar em branco
          present: deve ficar em branco
          confirmation: não é igual a %{attribute}
          empty: não pode ficar vazio
          equal_to: deve ser igual a %{count}
          even: deve ser par
          exclusion: não está disponível
          greater_than: deve ser maior que %{count}
          greater_than_or_equal_to: deve ser maior ou igual a %{count}
          inclusion: não está incluído na lista
          invalid: não é válido
          less_than: deve ser menor que %{count}
          less_than_or_equal_to: deve ser menor ou igual a %{count}
          not_a_number: não é um número
          not_an_integer: não é um número inteiro
          odd: deve ser ímpar
          record_invalid: ! 'A validação falhou: %{errors}'
          restrict_dependent_destroy:
            one: "Não é possível excluir o registro pois existe um %{record} dependente"
            many: "Não é possível excluir o registro pois existem %{record} dependentes"
          taken: já está em uso
          too_long: ! 'é muito longo (máximo: %{count} caracteres)'
          too_short: ! 'é muito curto (mínimo: %{count} caracteres)'
          wrong_length: não possui o tamanho esperado (%{count} caracteres)
          other_than: "deve ser diferente de %{count}"
        template:
          body: ! 'Por favor, verifique o(s) seguinte(s) campo(s):'
          header:
            one: ! 'Não foi possível gravar %{model}: 1 erro'
            other: ! 'Não foi possível gravar %{model}: %{count} erros.'
      helpers:
        select:
          prompt: Por favor selecione
        submit:
          create: Criar %{model}
          submit: Salvar %{model}
          update: Atualizar %{model}
      number:
        currency:
          format:
            delimiter: .
            format: ! '%u %n'
            precision: 2
            separator: ! ','
            significant: false
            strip_insignificant_zeros: false
            unit: R$
        format:
          delimiter: .
          precision: 3
          separator: ! ','
          significant: false
          strip_insignificant_zeros: false
        human:
          decimal_units:
            format: ! '%n %u'
            units:
              billion:
                one: bilhão
                other: bilhões
              million:
                one: milhão
                other: milhões
              quadrillion:
                one: quatrilhão
                other: quatrilhões
              thousand: mil
              trillion:
                one: trilhão
                other: trilhões
              unit: ''
          format:
            delimiter: .
            precision: 2
            significant: true
            strip_insignificant_zeros: true
          storage_units:
            format: ! '%n %u'
            units:
              byte:
                one: Byte
                other: Bytes
              gb: GB
              kb: KB
              mb: MB
              tb: TB
        percentage:
          format:
            delimiter: .
            format: "%n%"
        precision:
          format:
            delimiter: .
      support:
        array:
          last_word_connector: ! ' e '
          two_words_connector: ! ' e '
          words_connector: ! ', '
      time:
        am: ''
        formats:
          default: ! '%a, %d de %B de %Y, %H:%M:%S %z'
          long: ! '%d de %B de %Y, %H:%M'
          short: ! '%d de %B, %H:%M'
        pm: ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim amigo:

```
activerecord:
  models:
    user: Usuário
attributes:
  user:
    name: "Nome"
    email: "E-mail"
    password: "Senha"
    password_confirmation: "Senha Confirmação"
```

Comment: Olá Jefferson, já tinha testado desta forma. Será que tem algo a ver com o fato de eu estar usando MongoID, que não usa activerecord?

Comment: Exatamente. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465481/whats-the-way-to-translate-model-attributes-in-rails-with-mongoid

Answer (score 0):

Como estou usando Mongoid, não deve ser usado o activerecord, logo o código fica da seguinte for

```
pt-BR:
  mongoid:
    models:
      user: 
        one: "Usuário"
        other: "Usuários"
    attributes:
      user:
        name: "Nome"
        email: "E-mail"
        password: "Senha"
        password_confirmation: "Senha Confirmação"
...
```